# Erro e Aviso ao alterar a plataforma de AnyCPU para x64

Tags: c#, x86, 64-bits, x64, 32-bits

Eu tinha um problema, que, ao tentar capturar processos 64 bites em plataforma x86, ocorria um erro de exceção. Consegui resolvê-lo criando uma aplicação 64 e uma 32 bites. Arrumei todas as dlls, enfim, tudo perfeito...certo? Errado.
Ocorreu um erro, que não atrapalha em nada a execução e a performance do programa, porém, ele está me incomodando.

[image]

Bem...esse é o erro que ocorre. Já abri o CSproj e troquei tudo o que estava em x86 e AnyCPU para x64, arrumei os caminhos mas, o erro permanece.
Alguém sabe como resolver?
Antes que me enviem links e mais links, saibam que eu provavelmente já pesquisei em quase todos antes de vir até aqui perguntar. Porém, caso achem que é necessário a url para que eu resolva o problema, então fiquem a vontade.
Como eu disse, esse erro não atrapalha em nada mas, como essa aplicação esta sendo levada a sério pela minha pessoa, adoraria que não houvesse erro algum.
Obrigado.